# Wait for Android Listener to complete

Tags: android, locking, listener, semaphore, nonblocking

I got a notifyDataSetChanged function and i NEED to receive location changes within that methode and execute another methode AFTER i did receive these changes.
The Problem is, that i have to give android a locationlistener and let the service locate gps position and then call my listener function. I need all that to happen within notifyDataSetChanged.

My approach:

```
@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {
    Log.i(Constants.LOG_TAG, "entering notifyDataSetChanged()");
    try {
        semaphore.acquire();

        Looper.prepare();
        Log.i(Constants.LOG_TAG, "requesting GPS updates..");
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.i(Constants.LOG_TAG, "got a location: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
                locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                loadData(location);

                semaphore.release();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        });
        Looper.loop();

//Wait for loadData to finish after i got the location
        semaphore.acquire();
        semaphore.release();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(Constants.LOG_TAG, "exiting notifyDataSetChanged()");
}
```

However "exiting notifyDataSetChanged()" is never done...

Any ideas?

Best regards
John

Comment: so call another method in `onLocationChanged`

Comment: There is no guarantee that you are going to *ever* get a location fix. The user may have the GPS provider disabled in Settings. Or, the user may be in a location (e.g., parking garage, conference center) where they cannot get a GPS fix. Anyone attempting to get location fixes has to deal with the case where a location fix will never arrive. And `$DEITY` help you if `onDataSetChanged()` is being called on the main application thread, as you try to block it for long periods of time while trying to get location fixes. Perhaps you need to reorganize your code to be more event-driven.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#loop()), it says: Be sure to call quit() to end the loop. ;)